# Too many connections while using gevent socketio

Tags: gunicorn, gevent, gevent-socketio, greenlets, mysql-error-1040

I am getting too many connections (1040) when using gevent socketio. I am using monkey patch right now. Can I limit the number of threads(greenlets) created and make some jobs share the threads? I am using gunicorn and django.

Answer (score 0):

Well try using `gevent.pool()` in your code, which you can give a limit on how many greenlets it can spawn. Your question is to 'general' to answer. You need give more information about the context and source of the spawning of greenlets.